# Binary Numbers. Error When Checking to be sure binary input is binary

Tags: c++, string, binary, ascii

I'm writing a simple loop to make sure my input is a valid binary. Ex: I want to throw an error when any number higher than one is user input. I know I need to check against the ASCII numbers. What is going on here? I should not be getting an error when I input binary. Any thoughts?

```
for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    printf("%i is string sub %i\n",int(binary[i]),i);
    if (int(binary[i]) != 48 || int(binary[i]) != 49)
    {
        printf("ERROR NOT A BINARY NUMBER\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

input:

```
0101
```

Output:

```
48 is string sub 0
ERROR NOT A BINARY NUMBER
```

Comment: without the definition of `binary[]` this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `if (int(binary[i]) != 48 && int(binary[i]) != 49)` - note && rather than ||.  As it stood, the `if(...)` was effectively `if(true)` as `binary[i]` could not be both 48 and 49 simultaneously.

Comment: np - glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong boolean operator. If you read your if statement out loud, this is what it sounds like:

*Execute what is inside the if statement if binary[i] is not '0' OR if it is not '1'.*

How can it be two things at the same time?

Use `&&` instead of `||`.